# Ruby failed to build native gem

Tags: ruby, devkit, mkmf

I'm trying to make Ruby development environment portable, and I've had a few issues localising DevKit. It installed fine, but when I try to install a gem that requires it (in this case, `wdm`). The contents of `mkmf.log` can be found below:

```
"gcc -o conftest.exe -IE:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IE:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IE:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LE:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
In file included from E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from conftest.c:1:
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:131:14: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from conftest.c:1:
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_freeze_inline':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1360:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1361:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1362:6: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1362:27: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_get':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1400:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_object_make':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1414:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_data_typed_object_make':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1421:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1587:41: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1588:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1949:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1966:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
In file included from E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from conftest.c:1:
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_clone_setup':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1997:56: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1998:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1999:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1999:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_dup_setup':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2005:42: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2006:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2006:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_array_len':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2012:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2013:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2013:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_array_const_ptr':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2027:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_struct_len':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2034:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2035:2: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2035:26: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_struct_const_ptr':
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
E:/Resources/Windows/Software/Ruby/RubyPortable/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:2041:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
```

The ruby installation is working fine, I'm not sure what's causing this. All gems that don't require devkit work OK, but DevKit just isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things, you either are pretty close and have done most of this, or you have `gcc` in your `PATH` somewhere that isn't the DevKit, but I'll explain the entire process on how I would do it if I was going to. *NOTE: I don't want to, ever. =(*

**This answer is really dense because of all the things that are happening.

In other words, you have to really want to make this work.

Don't expect to copy/paste the code and things work without understanding what's going on.**

The DevKit "installs" with absolute paths. If you want to change that you'll have do some really **dirty work** to make it work.

The `rb` file that loads the *DevKit* is actually located at `<ruby>/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb` assuming `<ruby>` is the root installation directory. So you'll need to open that.
*NOTE: This file is loaded in a different part of the installation process.*

Then assuming that the `devkit` folder location is in the same location as your `ruby` folder, *e.g.* `E:\folderA\ruby` and `E:\FolderA\devkit` you'll need to change it to look something like this:

```
# enable RubyInstaller DevKit usage as a vendorable helper library
devkit_root = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../../..', 'devkit'))
msys_bin_path = File.join(devkit_root, 'bin').gsub(File::SEPARATOR, File::ALT_SEPARATOR)
mingw_bin_path = File.join(devkit_root, 'mingw', 'bin').gsub(File::SEPARATOR, File::ALT_SEPARATOR)

unless ENV['PATH'].include?(mingw_bin_path) then
  phrase = 'Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...'
  if defined?(Gem)
    Gem.ui.say(phrase) if Gem.configuration.verbose
  else
    puts phrase
  end
  puts "Prepending ENV['PATH'] to include DevKit..." if $DEBUG
  ENV['PATH'] = "#{msys_bin_path};#{mingw_bin_path};" + ENV['PATH']
end
ENV['RI_DEVKIT'] = devkit_root.gsub(File::SEPARATOR, File::ALT_SEPARATOR)
ENV['CC'] = 'gcc'
ENV['CXX'] = 'g++'
ENV['CPP'] = 'cpp'
```

If the location is any different then you'll have to change the `devkit_root` relative join.
If you want to confirm that the path exists, then you can use `realpath` instead of `expand_path`.

Now, if all of this looks similar then it's *probably* something with the `Makefile` generation from `extconf.rb` in the gem you're trying to install. In which case, you'll have to fix that in the `gem` and maybe open a PR if you're feeling charitable. But it could also be a ton of other things going wrong, so in essence **YMMV**.

Comment: It turns out I had the wrong architecture of `DevKit`. Smart right? -.-